# Delete copies of files from a directory according to their masks

Tags: python, regex, operating-system

Hello everyone from a mind-boiling amateur. To ease the process of files removing (over 700 units in a folder) there's a code where's complicated to create a logic what could compare two files in a folder with the similar names in the beginning and remove the one marked with 17 and left the one what includes 18 in it.
The example of files in a folder (ap_txap180101.jwl; bh_txbh171002.jwl; bh_txbh180101.jwl; dp_txdp170101.jwl... etc). As it's seen there are two files that have the same beginning "bh_txbh" but different unique numbers as 17 and 18. What's a method to compare the strings of names and apply to remove the file what contains 17 only. And the same for other files in the folder which have the same couples of them but differ from each other as it's described.

There's a code what I futile tried to compose for the task. Would be glad to hear ideas. It could be useful for filtering old content regarding names as I think.

```
import os
import re

dir_name = "/Python/Schems"
testfolder = os.listdir(dir_name)

regex = re.compile(r'^[1-9\w]{2}_[1-9\w]{4}[1][7][\d\w]+\.[\d\w]+')
compare = re.search.startswitch(r'^[1-9\w]{2}_[1-9\w]{4}[1][8]+', testfolder)

for ff in testfolder:
    k1 = regex.match(ff)
    k2 = compare.match(ff)
    if k1 == None:
        if k2 == compare:
            continue
            os.remove(os.path.join(dir_name, ff))
```

Comment: please indent your code properly; it is vital in Python

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/ohk9Lk/2

Comment: will it always be the case that the digits are 6 in total in the filename?

Comment: Ev. Kounis, certainly, working at this.

Comment: Ev. Kounis, there are any characters in file names. But the form of the beginning is always the similar: XX_XXXX17*.* (* - any number of characters).

Comment: Try like this - `regex = re.compile(r'\w{2}_\w{4}17')` and then inside `for` loop, `k = regex.match(regex)` and `if k: os.remove(os.path.join(dir_name, ff))`. Remove `compare` and all code related to it. See https://pastebin.com/i1WCXwef