# How to compare two files from filelist using regex?

Tags: python, regex, operating-system

The file is reading from a folder with os.listdir. After I entered regex of the file `r'^[1-9\w]{2}_[1-9\w]{4}[1][7][\d\w]+\.[\d\w]+'` and the similar for another file `r'^[1-9\w]{2}_[1-9\w]{4}[1][8]+'` . The condition of the comparison is that when the first seven symbols are matching then `os.remove(os.path.join(dir_name, each))` . Example of a few: bh_txbh171002.xml, bh_txbh180101.xml, ce_txce170101.xml...
As I understood we can't use match because there's no any string and it returns None, moreover it compares file with regex only. I am thinking about the condition `if folder.itself(file) and file.startswitch("......."):` But can't figure out how could I point the first seven symbols of file names what should be compared.

Honestly, I've placed my worse version of the code in that request and since that time I learnt a little bit more: [the link - press to check it up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48446676/delete-copies-of-files-from-a-directory-according-to-their-masks)

Comment: Your first regex is equal to `^\w{2}_\w{4}17\w+\.\w+` and the second one is equal to `^\w{2}_\w{4}18+`. Now, what do you want to do with them? Are they working as expected and if not, what is the problem? Please provide example strings with expected behavior.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I would like to compare each file what has the same format and if they have the similar beginning (7 symbols are equal) then removing of a file what includes 17 and leave with 18. Do that for each the similar files in the list.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew the code what I am futile trying to create is provided in the link what's left at the end of the question. Thanks for the questions

Answer (score 0):

Regex is the wrong tool here I do not have your files so I create randomized demodata:

```
import random
import string

random.seed(42)  # make random repeatable 

def generateFileNames(amount): 
    """Generate 2*amount of names XX_XXXX with X in [a-zA-T0-9] with duplicates in it"""

    def rndName():
        """generate one random name XX_XXXX with X in [a-zA-T0-9]"""
        characters = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
        return random.choices(characters,k=2)+['_']+random.choices(characters,k=4)

    for _ in range(amount):  # create 2*amount names, some duplicates
        name = rndName()
        yield ''.join(name)          # yield name once
        if random.randint(1,10) > 3: # more likely to get same names twice
            yield ''.join(name)          # same name twice
        else: 
            yield ''.join(rndName())     # different 2nd name


def generateNumberParts(amount):
    """Generate 2*amount of 6-digit-strings, some with 17+18 as starting numbers"""
    def rndNums(nr):
        """Generate nr digits as string list"""
        return random.choices(string.digits,k=nr)

    for _ in range(amount):
        choi = rndNums(4)
        # i am yielding 18 first to demonstrate that sorting later works
        yield ''.join(['18']+choi)    # 18xxxx numbers
        if random.randint(1,10) > 5:
            yield ''.join(['17']+choi) # 17xxxx  
        else: 
            yield ''.join(rndNums(6)) # make it something other


# half the amount of files generated 
m = 10

# generate filenames
filenames = [''.join(x)+'.xml' for x in zip(generateFileNames(m),
                                     generateNumberParts(m)]
```

Now I have my names as list and can start to find out which are dupes with newer timestamps:

```
# make a dict out of your filenames, use first 7 as key
# with list of values of files starting with this key a values:

fileDict={}
for names in filenames:
    fileDict.setdefault(names[0:7],[]).append(names) # create key=[] or/and append names

for k,v in fileDict.items():
    print (k, "    " , v)

# get files to delete (all the lower nr of the value-list if multiple in it)

filesToDelete = []

for k,v in fileDict.items():
    if len(v) == 1: # nothing to do, its only 1 file
        continue
    print(v, " to ", end = "" )         # debugging output
    v.sort(key = lambda x: int(x[7:9])) # sort by a lambda that integerfies 17/18
    print (v)                           # debugging output
    filesToDelete.extend(v[:-1])        # add all but the last file to the delete list

print("")
print(filesToDelete)
```

Output:

```
# the created filenames in your dict by "key      [values]"
xa_ji0y      ['xa_ji0y188040.xml', 'xa_ji0y501652.xml']
v3_a3zm      ['v3_a3zm181930.xml']
mm_jbqe      ['mm_jbqe171930.xml']
ck_w5ng      ['ck_w5ng180679.xml', 'ck_w5ng348136.xml']
zy_cwti      ['zy_cwti184296.xml', 'zy_cwti174296.xml']
41_iblj      ['41_iblj182983.xml', '41_iblj172983.xml']
5x_ff0t      ['5x_ff0t187453.xml']
sd_bdw2      ['sd_bdw2177453.xml']
vn_vqjt      ['vn_vqjt189618.xml', 'vn_vqjt179618.xml']
ep_q85j      ['ep_q85j185198.xml', 'ep_q85j175198.xml']
vf_1t2t      ['vf_1t2t180309.xml', 'vf_1t2t089040.xml']
11_ertj      ['11_ertj188425.xml', '11_ertj363842.xml']

# sorting the names by its integer at 8/9 position of name
['xa_ji0y188040.xml','xa_ji0y501652.xml'] to ['xa_ji0y188040.xml','xa_ji0y501652.xml']
['ck_w5ng180679.xml','ck_w5ng348136.xml'] to ['ck_w5ng180679.xml','ck_w5ng348136.xml']
['zy_cwti184296.xml','zy_cwti174296.xml'] to ['zy_cwti174296.xml','zy_cwti184296.xml']
['41_iblj182983.xml','41_iblj172983.xml'] to ['41_iblj172983.xml','41_iblj182983.xml']
['vn_vqjt189618.xml','vn_vqjt179618.xml'] to ['vn_vqjt179618.xml','vn_vqjt189618.xml']
['ep_q85j185198.xml','ep_q85j175198.xml'] to ['ep_q85j175198.xml','ep_q85j185198.xml']
['vf_1t2t180309.xml','vf_1t2t089040.xml'] to ['vf_1t2t089040.xml','vf_1t2t180309.xml']
['11_ertj188425.xml','11_ertj363842.xml'] to ['11_ertj188425.xml','11_ertj363842.xml']

# list of files to delete
['xa_ji0y188040.xml', 'ck_w5ng180679.xml', 'zy_cwti174296.xml', '41_iblj172983.xml', 
 'vn_vqjt179618.xml', 'ep_q85j175198.xml', 'vf_1t2t089040.xml', '11_ertj188425.xml']
```

Comment: that's good and almost working. I am making attempts to apply this for os.listdir() and check up a result. And it compares items from the list but delete xa_ji0y18XX... as well. I will try to make comparing files and leave only files with 18. Thx a lot for the idea

Comment: @AlexanderLarionov It deletes 18 because there is a 50, 34  and 60 in the value-lists that trumps the file with 18 in it when sorting by int. This is due to my randomized demodata, your data should be fine. you can simply plug in your filenames for your Directory into `for names in filenames:` and see which of your filenames would be deleted.

Comment: I understood. Thank you sir. Working at it. The result will be published. Perfect example what makes strain my brain.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what's wrong with my code. There I defined the list from certain folder, so that I could work at the strings in each file, right? Then I applied the conditions for filtering and further choice of the one file to delete.

```
import os


dir_name = "/Python/Test_folder/Schems"
filenames = os.listdir(dir_name)

for names in filenames:

filenames.setdefault(names[0:7],[]).append(names) # create key=[] or/and append names
for k,v in filenames.items():

filesToDelete = []      #ther's a syntax mistake. But I can't get it - there's the list or not?

for k,v in filenames.items():
if len(v) == 1:
   continue
      v.sort(key = lambda x: int(x[7:9]))
      filesToDelete.extend(v[:-1])
```